# Can $x^n=n^x$ be solved for $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

> Can the equation $x^n=n^x$ be solved for $n$ where $x \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$.

I have tried to simplify it using logarithms and properties of logs, but I can't isolate $n$. I transformed the equation to the form $n^{1/n}=x^{1/x}$ but this creates an issue if there is a negative value for $x$, which happens every time $n$ is even.

Comment: By inspection, $x = n$ is always a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I don't want the solution x=n. There should be at least one other non-trivial solution for all whole numbers n greater than 0.

Comment: x and n are reals? positive? integers?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti x and n are real, n is a positive integer.

Comment: 2^4=4^2  is such a solution ( if you don't find it trivial).

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee you are right, that is not a trivial solution, but I am trying to find a general solution for n

Comment: any restrictions like x<n or n<x ? that may affect the answer.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee no

Comment: $n=x^{\frac{n}{x}}$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n=1 \implies x=1$. Otherwise fix $n\ge 2$ integer. The function $f(x)=\log x/x$ (for $x>0$) is such that $f^\prime(x)=(1-\log x)/x^2$. Hence $f$ is increasing in $(0,e]$ and decreasing otherwise. Note also that 
$$
f(0^+)=-\infty, f(1)=0, f(e)=1/e, \text{ and }\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0^+. 
$$
That means that for each $n\ge 2$ integer there exists a unique $x>0$ such that $x\neq n$ and $x^n=n^x$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Lambert-W function, $W(z)$ is the inverse of $ze^z$,

$$ n = -\frac{xW(\frac{-\log x}{x})}{\log x} $$

**Edit:**
First notice that $x^n = n^x \implies \frac{\log n}{n} = \frac{\log x}{x}$. Then use the definition of the Lambert function, $z = W(t) \implies t = ze^z$ and rewrite the original expression as,

$$ \frac{n\log x}{-x} e^{\frac{n
log x}{-x}} = -\frac{\log x}{x} $$ and from here you should be able to show that $\frac{\log n}{n} = \frac{\log x}{x}$.

Comment: what steps did you use to solve for n?